# Lots of mail with attachments

Tags: thunderbird

*This is the last one regarding Thunderbird3 handling of mails, I promise :-)*

I never used it, and the fella I'm setting it up often receives mails with attachments - in size from 1 to 10 mb (in short, it collects up over the months).

He had problems with Outlook, and that's why I suggested moving to Thunderbird. Now, just to be sure, I'm asking. Can he expect some problems with that scenario ?

A lot of mails with attachments in the inbox is bad ... I told him to archive anything he doesn't need. How does archiving mails deal with attachments differently from just leaving them in inbox ?

Can he expect a major slowdown and corruption of mails over the time ? Experiences ?

*For reasons not specified, separating attachments from mails is not an option for now. Not even considered at this point.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My e-mail address at work receives a number of attachments. I recently cleaned it out, but it's still over 5.5 GB used on my hard drive. I've been using Thunderbird since the beta version of 2 and I have no complaints with message corruption. The mailbox has outlived 3 computers and 4 different operating systems (XP, Vista, Ubuntu 8.04 and OS X 10.5).

I think your "friend" should be fine with Thunderbird.

Comment: :-) Thank you ... pretty much what I hoped to hear !

Answer (score 1):

> Can he expect ... corruption of mails

always be prepared for the unexpected and create regular backups ... it's just a few mouse clicks with [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/).

Comment: Nice in theory, but rarely done in practice amongst the non computer oriented users.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `IMAP` instead of `POP` and not downloading the attachments (keeping them on the server)?

Comment: I don't think he has IMAP available. I just know they have often some server trouble (SMTP doesn't work half the time for some reason) ...